# API Endpoints in Strapi V4

Tags: strapi

I'm **new** to Strapi and Following Strapi Tutorial Playlist in Youtube.Youtube Playlist is old and He is using Strapi V3. But Current Version is `4.0.5`. I facing problem in using `API` Endpoint.

I created **Collection** type and named it as `Posts`.I even published it.When I navigate to `http://localhost:1337/api/posts`, It returns

```
{
  "data": null,
  "error": {
    "status": 403,
    "name": "ForbiddenError",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "details": {}
  }
}
```

Does somebody help me please?

Answer (score 4):

If you try to retrieve the data as a public user, then you need to go to roles and set the appropriate rights.

Settings -> Users & Permissions -> Roles -> Public -> Posts

then make sure find and fineone are checked.

Comment: I can't find Settings -> Users & Permissions in Strapi v4.x

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I needed to set a `scope` for the `auth` configs of the route.

Like this (please note the `scope`):

```
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/custom-route',
      handler: 'custom-controller.getCustomMethod',
      config: {
        policies: [],
        auth: {
          scope: ['find'],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Anyone keen to comment why the negative vote? I'd be interested :)